# Переопределение метода с внесением условий по дате в java

Tags: java, calendar, переопределение

В классе `DepositAccount`, который наследует класс `BankAccount`, метод `take()` переопределен так, чтобы снятие со счета ранее, чем через месяц после последнего пополнения было невозможно. Подскажите, как вписать возможность снятия денег более, чем через месяц.

```
 public class BankAccount {
    private double balance;

    public double getAmount() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void put(double amountToPut) {
        if (amountToPut >= 0) {
            balance = amountToPut + balance;
        }
    }

    public void take(double amountToTake) {
        if ((balance >= amountToTake) && (amountToTake >= 0)) {
            balance = balance - amountToTake;
        }
    }
```

```
public class DepositAccount extends BankAccount {

    @Override
    public void take(double amountToTake) {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar lastIncome = Calendar.getInstance();
        lastIncome.add(today.MONTH, -1);
        if (lastIncome.after(today)) {
            super.take(amountToTake);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Временные отметки должны сохраняться для любых транзакций (движений по счёту) не только для депозитного, но и для обычного счёта, для чего в классе `BaseAccount` имеет смысл завести коллекцию/мапу для сохранения последних меток в зависимости от типа транзакции.

Также, для хранения информации следует использовать хотя бы класс-обёртку [`java.sql.Timetamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), а вообще *крайне* рекомендуется пользоваться Java Date/Time API, в частности классом [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), появившемуся в Java 8, вместо устаревших классов `Date`/`Calendar`

ИСпользовать типы с плавающей точкой для работы с финансами [не рекомендуется](https://habr.com/ru/post/338108/)

> *Большинство дробных чисел в десятичной системе счисления не имеют точного представления в виде конечной суммы степеней двойки.*

```java
import java.time.*;

public class BankAccount {
    private long balance;
    protected Instant lastPutTime;
    protected Instant lastTakeTime;

    public long getAmount() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void put(long amountToPut) {
        if (amountToPut >= 0) {
            balance += amountToPut;
            lastPutTime = Instant.now();
        }
    }

    public void take(long amountToTake) {
        if (amountToTake >= 0 && balance >= amountToTake) {
            balance -= amountToTake;
            lastTakeTime = Instant.now();
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда для депозитного счёта можно просто добавить проверку по времени:

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

public class DepositAccount extends BankAccount {

    @Override
    public void take(long amountToTake) {
        if (null != lastPutTime // должно быть хотя бы одно пополнение счёта
            && Instant.now().isAfter(lastPutTime.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS))) {
            super.take(amountToTake);
        } else {
            // залогировать попытку снятия денег прежде времени
            // и/или выбросить исключение
            throw new TooEarlyWithdrawalException();
        }
    }
}
```