# Java, как зафиксировать время конкретной операции и сравнить ее с другой датой

Tags: java, calendar, localdate

Дамы и Господа, Решаю задачу, язык Java.  В определенном методе происходит пополнение баланса, а в другом методе этого класса происходит списание баланса, моя задача сделать так, что бы списание баланса не могло происходить, если с момента последнего пополнения ни прошло месяца. Для решения необходимо добавить переменную , в которой хранится дата последнего внесения,и тип этой переменной должен быть Calendar или LocalDate.

Т.е. суть вопроса в том как мне привязать пополнение баланса к конкретной дате и какой метод лучше подойдет для сравнения ее с другой датой.

```
  public void put(double toPut) {
// метод зачисляет деньги на счет
if (toPut >= 0) {
  balance = toPut + balance;
} else {
  System.out.println("Операция не может быть выполнена");
}
```

}

```
public void take ( double toTake){
 //  метод списывает деньги со счета
  if (balance > toTake) {
    balance = balance - toTake ;
  } else {System.out.println("Операция не может быть выполнена");
}
```

}

Comment: [Вопрос-дубликат: Переопределение метода с внесением условий по дате в java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1369954/386633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так, наверное

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

class balance
{
    public LocalDate lastDate;
    public double balance;
    
    public void put(double toPut) {
    // метод зачисляет деньги на счет
    if (toPut >= 0) {
      balance = toPut + balance;
      lastDate = LocalDate.of(2022,8,27); //  LocalDate.now();
    } else {
      System.out.println("Операция не может быть выполнена");
    }
    }
    
    public void take (double toTake){
     //  метод списывает деньги со счета
      if ((balance > toTake) &&  (LocalDate.now().minusDays(30).compareTo(lastDate)>0)) {
        balance = balance - toTake;
      } else System.out.println("Операция не может быть выполнена");
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        balance myb = new balance();
        myb.put(200);
        myb.take(100);
        
        System.out.println("Последнее пополнение было: " + myb.lastDate);
        System.out.println("Текущий баланс: " + myb.balance);
    }
}
```

```
Операция не может быть выполнена
Последнее пополнение было: 2022-08-27
Текущий баланс: 200.0
```

Comment: Да, благодарю, это то, что нужно